# iPhone SDK: To show HTML Web page content description in my View:

Tags: iphone

I need to show a web page content in my application view. What are the ways that can be done for that programmatically in iPhone development? For example, I need to access and show the following page: http://www.business-standard.com/india/storypage.php?autono=73165&tp=on

Do I need to download and get HTML data from this url using NSURLConnection on my iPhone client app and parse the HTML data and show the content in my view? In this case, if we launch this link and show view source, there are very critical html tag provided to parse the content description, so how to do that in my client app perfectly? If there is any sample, please give me?

Or else, is it possible to give this link to an API call directly and show the web page view in my client app itself instead of getting data and parsing work? P.S: I shouldn't launch web browser and show the page.

Can anyone please check this link and suggest the ways to do and provide me some samples?

Comment: This question is reliant on the link, and that is now redirecting. I will try to put the question on hold.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a [`UIWebView`](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)? If it doesn't meet your needs, could you describe a bit more what about it is lacking?

Comment: thanks. 
I could able launch my web page using UIWebView by following NSURLRequest and loadRequest API calls. I have a question is that can i show public web pages in my client app like this right? It is not illegal right?

Comment: You can load and view any web page accessible with a URL, so the page could be in the Resources folder of your app or somewhere out on the internet. (Note, though, that you'll need an active internet connection to view a site.) IANAL, but unless there are legal restrictions imposed by the site you are trying to display there is nothing wrong with doing what you're trying to do.

Comment: That's Great. Anyway finally I'm going to access my server public IP only, not any other third party one. I am just testing using other pages now.